# How to get location after updates?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I followed a tutorial to use google maps API to get last known location or request location updates if there were no such location.

Here is my onConnected method

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.v(TAG, "old location" + location);

    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
        Log.v(TAG, "new location");
    }
}
```

So the first conditional is supposed to request a new location. Where is this location stored? I thought it might execute handeNewLocation (the code is below)

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    loc = "Latitude: " + Double.toString(currentLatitude) + ", Longitude: " + Double.toString(currentLongitude);
    Log.v(TAG, loc);
}
```

I need to get the location and store it as a string, so my problem is I don't know where exactly

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

is saving the new location.

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GiveActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_give"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ashkanbakhshai.com.greenlight.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PopActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pop"
        android:theme="@style/fullScreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignatureActivity"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signature"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OwnerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_owner"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TakeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_take"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignatureOwnActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signature_own"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GreenLighted"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_green_lighted"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameOwnActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_own" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RedLighted"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_red_lighted"
        android:theme="@style/giveFull" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailHistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_history" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NavigationActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ExitActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_exit"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ExitOwnActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_exit_own"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HisListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_his_list" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ashkanbakhshai.com.greenlight.HistoryActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameAltActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_alt" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameOwnAltActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_own_alt" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.AIzaSyBhbrcIcN2yQV883z8bwe3Mm5-PnHUgmlI"
        android:value="AIzaSyBhbrcIcN2yQV883z8bwe3Mm5-PnHUgmlI" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to request location updates does just that, it requests location updates.

After you make that call, new locations will come in to `onLocationChanged()`

If you want to always have the current location saved, you can do so with member variables.

Note that there is no need to log a null location as you are doing now, so remove the log entry in the case that location is null:

```
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
        Log.v(TAG, "new location");
    }
```

Then update member variables in `handleNewLocation()`:

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude(); //update member variable
    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude(); //update member variable
    loc = "Latitude: " + Double.toString(currentLatitude) + ", Longitude: " + Double.toString(currentLongitude);
    Log.v(TAG, loc);
}
```

Then, call `handleNewLocation()` in the `onLocationChanged()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //location changed, update current location
    handleNewLocation(location);
    Log.v(TAG, "new location");

}
```

Full class:

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    double currentLatitude; //added as member variable
    double currentLongitude; //added as member variable
    String TAG = "myapp";
    String loc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"buildGoogleApiClient",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);

        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
            Log.v(TAG, "new location");
        }

    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude(); //update member variable
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude(); //update member variable
        loc = "Latitude: " + Double.toString(currentLatitude) + ", Longitude: " + Double.toString(currentLongitude);
        Log.v(TAG, loc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //location changed, update current location
        handleNewLocation(location);
        Log.v(TAG, "new location");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    Log.v(TAG, "old location" + location);
```

before you call

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

then the location will be stored in `location`.

Comment: Then my conditions won't work, because I'm testing if location is null and I actually do need to request location updates or if I can just use location. Do you think the if statement is unnecessary?

Comment: yes, I've done this exact thing [before](https://github.com/KevCron/Tracking/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kevincronly/trackingapp/Tracker.java).

Comment: I'm doing exactly this and location is null. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sure I've done so. Edit: I just added it (you didn't miss anything).